# How to pass extra arguments to the django log formatter

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to do the following:

```
    # settings.py
    'json': {
        'format': 'Avails: {"levelname": "%(levelname)s", "asctime": "%(asctime)s", "funcName": "%(funcName)s", "filename": "%(filename)s", "lineno": "%(lineno)s", "message": "%(message)s"}',
    },
```

And in the view:

```
log.info('this is my message', extra={'user': request.user}
```

How would I grab the `extra` info in the log formatter?

Answer (score 2):

The user in `extra` can be added in the logging json formatter  as

```
'json': {
    'format': (
        'Avails: {'
            '"levelname": "%(levelname)s",'
            '"asctime": "%(asctime)s",'
            '"funcName": "%(funcName)s",'
            '"filename": "%(filename)s",'
            '"lineno": "%(lineno)s",'
            '"message": "%(message)s",' 
            '"user": "%(user)s"'
        '}',
    )
},
```

**Note that** you need to pass a string value for user instead of the user object in the extra options. When this is not a string object, the `__repr__` or `__str__` value of the object passed replaces the corresponding conversion specification in the format string.

```
log.info('this was your message :D', extra={'user': request.user.pk}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/logging/#configure-a-formatter), you can format logging any fields you wish to log. Likewise

```
LOGGING = {
    [...]
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{name} {levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
}
```