# multiple arguments in logger and use them in formater - django

Tags: python, django, logging, formatting, python-logging

I want to send multiple arguments in logger messages and use them directly in formater.

For example,

`logger.exception('Exception message, 'arg1', 'arg2') logger.warning('warning message, 'arg1', 'arg2')`

And in formater. I want to use args like
`'[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s|%(name)s|0|0|%(message)s|%(args1)s|%(args2)s'`

I don't want to use *args and **kwargs for these arguments.
Is there any way to implement this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe duplication;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289691/how-to-pass-extra-arguments-to-the-django-log-formatter

Comment: @SezerBOZKIR I want to send arguments directly without sending them in the extra keyword.

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593570/5942941